# What is a good book to learn about Lamination?

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, hyperbolic-geometry

I would like to learn about Lamination in a geometric approach or a dynamical system approach. Please recommend me some good book! Many thanks!

Comment: How about Candel and Conlon?

Comment: Thank you so much! That seems like a good book, but I don't know if it is good for a beginner. I prefer a book with more pictures.

Comment: The first few chapters of it might be more to your taste; there are more pictures and diagrams the in the rest of the book, and the algebraic and geometric topology requirements aren't as steep.

Comment: For a geometric approach to 1-dimensional laminations in hyperbolic surfaces, take a look at the book by Casson and Bleiler.